# Compare constexpr array of bytes with part of the buffer (pointer to data)

Tags: c++, c++17

I have defined the following constants:

```
constexpr uint8_t msgHeader[] = { 0x44, 0x44, 0x53, 0x20 };
constexpr uint8_t msgHeaderSize = sizeof(msgHeader) / sizeof(msgHeader[0]);
```

Next I have a function which provides pointer to the message data and I need to check if a message header is valid. Here is an example code:

```
void IsHeaderValid(uint8_t* msg)
{
    uint8_t currentHeader[msgHeaderSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < msgHeaderSize; ++i)
    {
        currentHeader[i] = msg[i];
    }

    if(strcmp(currentHeader, msgHeader))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;  
}
```

Could you recommend any other (simpler/cleaner) method of comparing constexpr msgHeader with incoming message ?

Comment: A better way would be any other way that does not trigger undefined behavior and a possible crash, like this one, because, as you must know, `strcmp()` expects `'\0'`-terminated strings, and this one isn't.

Comment: [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) is for comparing null-terminated byte strings. Your "strings" aren't that. Use [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp) instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude /s `memcmp`

Comment: You don't need to use that `sizeof` trick. There is `std::size` function for that.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Oops, brainfart I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use your [algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal):

```cpp
bool IsHeaderValid(uint8_t* msg)
{
    return std::equal(msgHeader, msgHeader + msgHeaderSize, msg);
}
```

or

```cpp
bool IsHeaderValid(uint8_t* msg)
{
    return std::equal(std::begin(msgHeader), std::end(msgHeader), msg);
}
```